# Unable to remove an action for a page template in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, hook

```
function hide_editor_page(){
  global $_wp_post_type_features;
  $post_type= "page";
  $feature = "editor";
  if(isset($_wp_post_type_features[$post_type][$feature])):
    unset($_wp_post_type_features[$post_type][$feature]);
  endif;
} 

function test1(){
    global $template;
    global $_wp_post_type_features;
    $post_type= "page";
    $feature = "editor";
        if(basename($template) == "contact.php"):
            remove_action("init","hide_editor_page",10);
        endif;
}
add_action('init','test1',5);
```

Can anyone suggest The hide_editor_page is working fine but when try to remove the same using test1 using the basename($template) condition it's not working. Without the basename($template) condition remove_action is working.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1**

If your contact.php page does not make any HTTP GET requests, try using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `basename($template)`

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "contact.php"):
            remove_action("init","hide_editor_page",10);
        endif;
```

**SOLUTION 2**

If `example.com/whatever/` is your URL, it will return `whatever` in `$current_slug`

```
global $wp;
$current_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );
if($current_slug == "contact.php"):
            remove_action("init","hide_editor_page",10);
        endif;
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: I have tried both the solutions but no luck, Thanks.

Comment: ```basename($template)``` will return the Template name instead of the page name. Whereas SOLUTION 1 should have worked in your case. ```$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']``` returns the part after domain which would be ```contact.php```. Better option: do ```var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);``` before condition and check the value on Contact Page. Then change ```contact.php``` to ```VALUE```. This is a workaround which has a 100% success rate! LOL...

Comment: I actually require the funtion to work wih template-name.php not with the page-name. if you obserb the "hide_editor_page()" its unset the default wordpress editor for the pages. I just need to unset the function on a perticular page template where the "hide_editor_page()" funtion will unset.
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) also not working.